# How to route an url with an url in it in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Basically I would like to take an url like:

http://example.com/community/www.foo.com/bar

...and give it to my http://example.com/community/ view with [www.foo.com/bar](http://www.foo.com/bar) in some variable that razor can access in the view.

How could this be done?

Note: I tried this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Community",                                           
    "{controller}/{url}",                           
    new { controller = "Community", action = "Index", url = "" }
);
```

which worked with http://example.com/community/www.foo.com but not http://example.com/community/www.foo.com/bar (IIS tried to resolve the latter and gave a 404).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Sometimes you have to handle URL requests that contain a variable
> number of URL segments. When you define a route, you can specify that
> if a URL has more segments than there are in the pattern, the extra
> segments are considered to be part of the last segment. To handle
> additional segments in this manner you mark the last parameter with an
> asterisk (*). This is referred to as a catch-all parameter. A route
> with a catch-all parameter will also match URLs that do not contain
> any values for the last parameter. The following example shows a route
> pattern that matches an unknown number of segments.
>
> ```
> query/{queryname}/{*queryvalues}
> ```

In your case it will be:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Community",                                           
    "{controller}/{*url}",                           
    new { controller = "Community", action = "Index", url = "" }
);
```

Alternative and more robust approach is using some kind of encoding for the URL part - for example Base64URI encoding from [RFC4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648)

Comment: This solved my problem - thank you so much. Great amount of detail, thanks.